# Fama MacBeth standard errors in R

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, panel-data

Does anyone know if there is a package that would run Fama-MacBeth regressions in R and calculate the standard errors?  I am aware of the `sandwich` package and its ability to estimate Newey-West standard errors, as well as providing functions for clustering.  However, I have not seen anything with respect to Fama-MacBeth.

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("macbeth")` finds nothing, but `findFn("fama")` gets a few hits in finance-related packages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `plm` package can estimate Fama-MacBeth regressions and SEs.

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
test <- read.dta("http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/test_data.dta")
fpmg <- pmg(y~x, test, index=c("year","firmid")) ##Fama-MacBeth

> ##Fama-MacBeth
> coeftest(fpmg)

t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.031278   0.023356  1.3392   0.1806    
x           1.035586   0.033342 31.0599   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However note that this method works only if your data can be coerced to a `pdata.frame`. (It will fail if you have `"duplicate couples (time-id)"`.)

For further details see:

- [Fama-MacBeth and Cluster-Robust (by Firm and Time) Standard Errors in R](http://landroni.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/fama-macbeth-and-cluster-robust-by-firm-and-time-standard-errors-in-r/)

Comment: in the example coeftest(fpmg) does not handle double-clustered standard errors. Please show how to do it for fpmg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441230/r-no-way-to-get-double-clustered-standard-errors-for-an-object-of-class-cpmg

Comment: One person wrote that we need to swap N and T and everyone is doing it. I see others who have questioned it, but they have been silenced ;)

Comment: Both orders work on `df.petersen`. `pmg` is supposed to average time series. Sometimes averaging crossections makes theoretical sense. In FM regression: the RHS variable is an index: the same for all ids. Try: `df.petersen2<-data.table(df.petersen);
df.petersen2[,`:=`(x=df.petersen2[firmid==1,x]),by="firmid"]`. Then try `summary(pmg(y ~ x, data=df.petersen2, index=c("year","firmid")))`. You will get NAs, as you are running crossections with no RHS variation. `pmg` is not well documented, so I am not sure if it does a proper FM regression, but `index=c("firmid","year"))` produces an estimate.

Comment: Looking further into this: `pmg` runs just one set of regressions and then takes averages. (not two sets of regressions) So one should populate x with beta estimates from the first FM regression and then use `pmg` on crosssections. For averaging crossections one should use `index=c("year","firmid")`, NB: with this approach errors in estimating betas are lost.