# obtaining average coefficients and adj. R^2 from multiple pooled regressions using lapply

Tags: r, lapply, plm

I have performed multiple Pooled regressions with a loop function and stored the regression output in a list (myregression). What I would like to do now is to efficiently perform the coeftest function in the lmtest package over all  my regressions (i.e., myregression list) to adjust standard errors and t-statistics. Finally I would like to obtain the mean of the coefficients, standard errors and t-values.

Here is what I came up so far:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

# Store each subset regression in myregression
myregression <- list()

count <- 1

# Regression on six-year subsets of Grunfeld
for(t in 1940:1950){

  myregression[[count]] <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, 
                              subset(Grunfeld, year<=t & year>=t-5),
                              index=c("firm","year"))

# Name each regression based on the year range included in the data subset
names(myregression)[[count]] = paste0("Year_",t)
count <- count+1
}
```

Here is where my problems kick in: Although i'm able to perform the coeftest function to invidiual components of the list, I'm unable to code the lapply function accordingly.

```
## Apply coeftest function to all plm-objects
library(lmtest)

coeftest(myregression$Year_1940, vcov=function(x) vcovSCC(x, type="HC3", maxlag=4))
coeftest(myregression$Year_1941, vcov=function(x) vcovSCC(x, type="HC3", maxlag=4))

COEFTEST<-lapply(myregression, coeftest(x, vcov=function(x) vcovSCC(x, type="HC3", maxlag=4)))

## obtaining average coefficients, se's,and t values over all regressions
lapply(COEFTEST, mean)
```

I hope there is only a minor mistake that I'm unable to see.
I further noticed that the plm regression output is smaller than regular lm output is there another way to obtain mean adj. R^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 COEFTEST<-lapply(myregression, function(x) coeftest(x, vcov=vcovSCC(x, type="HC3", maxlag=4)))
```

Thsi will give you a  list of coeftest-outputs for each regression, which you can then use in whatever way you want.

As a sidenote, make sure that whatever you do with this output makes sense. Taking the mean of an coeftest-output is not obvously sensible to me. If you want to have the average over all coefficients, try something like

```
 mean(sapply(COEFTEST, function(x)  x["capital", "Estimate"]))
```

Here, `sapply` retrieves all estimates for the variable `capital` from the `COEFTEST` outputs and puts them into a vector.

To access other elements, it is helpful to look at the structure of the objects using `str()`. For instance, `str(summary(myregression[[1]]))` reveals that the r-squares are saved under the name `r.squared`. These you can access using e.g. `summary(myregression[[1]])$r.squared` for the first regression output. Automating this, you can again use a construct as above, e.g.

```
 sapply(myregression, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helps a lot! The following lapply function with lapply(COEFTEST, mean) however gives back only one value per each regression. Is it not possible to obtain average values for each attribute?

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I was exactly wondering the same as i posted already this methodological question in cross-validate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107816/aggregating-pooled-regression-outputs-in-different-years, However no one replied thus far. I found multiple studies with pooled regressions in various years where they reported the following: "... reports the average coefficients and time-series Newey-West t-statistics from pooled regressions estimated each year, using the previous XX years of data" They do not provide more information on how they obtained it however

Comment: I was hesitating to accept as I still don't get how to retrieve certain elements of the summary function. For instance if i use lapply(myregression, summary) I would like to acces the "Adj. R-Squared" field of each regression and apply the mean function. Is this somehow possible? I would have accepted your answer anyway as only this minor issue is unresolved. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Thanks again for this very detailed answer! Thanks to this community I learned a lot in a very short time! aswome!

Comment: Here is what i was able to come up thanks to your help: mean(sapply(myregression, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared["adjrsq"])) and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nicer way to obtain average coefficients (technically known as Mean Group estimators) using `pmg()` in `plm`. And from the looks of it, you are trying to estimate Fama-MacBeth regressions and SEs.

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
test <- read.dta("http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/test_data.dta")
fpmg <- pmg(y~x, test, index=c("year","firmid")) ##Fama-MacBeth

> ##Fama-MacBeth
> coeftest(fpmg)

t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.031278   0.023356  1.3392   0.1806    
x           1.035586   0.033342 31.0599   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

For further details see [Fama-MacBeth and Cluster-Robust (by Firm and Time) Standard Errors in R](http://landroni.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/fama-macbeth-and-cluster-robust-by-firm-and-time-standard-errors-in-r/).

See also:

- [Fama MacBeth standard errors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034161/fama-macbeth-standard-errors-in-r/10998646#10998646)