# aggregating regression outputs in R

Tags: r, regression, lapply, sapply

I am performing multiple pooled cross-sectional regressions with a loop function and stored the regression outputs in a list (regression). What i would like to do now is to efficiently obtain the average coefficients, the average t-stats as well as the average adj.r squared.

I put up the following code already:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

# create list with regression outputs
regression <- list()

# Regression on past six-year subsets of Grunfeld in every year from 1940 to 1950
for(t in 1940:1950){

  regression[[as.character(t)]] <- lm(inv ~ value + capital, 
                              subset(Grunfeld, year<=t & year>=t-5))
}
```

This way I obtain the desired regression output stored in a list (regression). What i would like to do now is to efficiently obtain the average coefficients, the average t-stats as well as the average adj.r squared.

I already tried to calculated the mean of all the adj. r squared with the following:

```
mean(lapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$adj.r.squared))
```

However it seems that I am using the mean function wrong as i get the following error.

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(lapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$adj.r.squared)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Further i came up with the following to "extract" the coefficients.

```
lapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients)
```

How can I quickly obtain the average individual coefficients from this lapply output? (i.e extracting each row individually and calculate the respective mean over the years.)

```
$`1940`
               Estimate   Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -3.65239712 14.647050149 -0.2493606 8.039783e-01
value        0.08283141  0.006873563 12.0507230 2.615793e-17
capital      0.11033307  0.091543522  1.2052526 2.330857e-01

$`1941`
                Estimate   Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -13.77258038 16.677399231 -0.825823 4.123477e-01
value         0.08614094  0.007258571 11.867480 4.904857e-17
capital       0.18680229  0.094849038  1.969470 5.376624e-02

....
```

Comment: You get an error message because `lapply` returns a list and then you apply the `mean` function to this list. Use `sapply` instead as shown by @landroni.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820800/obtaining-average-coefficients-and-adj-r2-from-multiple-pooled-regressions-usi/25322808#25322808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
 library(reshape2)
  dcast(melt(lapply(regression, 
       function(x) summary(x)$coefficients)), Var1~Var2, value.var="value", mean)
 #         Var1    Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
 #1 (Intercept) -16.7072859 16.0876958 -1.029145 3.320868e-01
 #2       value   0.1107460  0.0076057 14.599109 1.510115e-17
 #3     capital   0.1279743  0.0685896  1.833861 9.389504e-02
```

Or

```
 Reduce(`+`,lapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients))/length(regression)
 #                    Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
 #(Intercept) -16.7072859 16.0876958 -1.029145 3.320868e-01
 #value         0.1107460  0.0076057 14.599109 1.510115e-17
 #capital       0.1279743  0.0685896  1.833861 9.389504e-02
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it right! Try this:

```
> sapply(regression, function(x) mean(summary(x)$adj.r.squared))
     1940      1941      1942      1943      1944      1945      1946      1947      1948      1949 
0.7230061 0.7293396 0.7399216 0.7770505 0.7998859 0.8413422 0.8571037 0.8561229 0.8348950 0.8357761 
     1950 
0.8324654
```

You may as well use `lapply()` in the above. The same can be done for any coefficient, t-test, once you identify how to extract them from the coefficient table.

To extract coefficients for `value` you can proceed as follows:

```
lapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[ rownames(summary(x)$coefficients)=="value", ])
```

A more compact version would be:

```
sapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[ rownames(summary(x)$coefficients)=="value", ])
```

From the above you can obtain means as follows:

```
> (x <- t(sapply(regression, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[ rownames(summary(x)$coefficients)=="value", ])))
       Estimate  Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
1940 0.08283141 0.006873563 12.05072 2.615793e-17
1941 0.08614094 0.007258571 11.86748 4.904857e-17
1942 0.09018745 0.007711639 11.69498 8.898811e-17
1943 0.09945565 0.007751087 12.83119 1.886416e-18
1944 0.10568804 0.007376523 14.32762 1.516617e-20
1945 0.11358598 0.006722166 16.89723 7.314450e-24
1946 0.12227763 0.006781509 18.03104 3.203995e-25
1947 0.12599497 0.007199027 17.50167 1.356383e-24
1948 0.12605599 0.008005481 15.74621 2.030259e-22
1949 0.12951740 0.008452725 15.32256 7.175275e-22
1950 0.13647072 0.009530406 14.31951 1.555615e-20
> colMeans(x)
    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
1.107460e-01 7.605700e-03 1.459911e+01 1.510115e-17
```

This said, this looks suspiciously like the Fama-MacBeth estimates: [Fama MacBeth standard errors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034161/fama-macbeth-standard-errors-in-r). These can be easily obtained using `pmg()` in `plm`.

Comment: thanks for your help. The "extraction" is exactly what I'm struggling with. What i would like to do ideally is to code it very flexible as that you can use different models (with different model parameters) and extract each row (for a respective variable) individually.